# How to perform certain task inside a fragment only when a TabLayout is active?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm working on an android app which involves token change on every data request to the server. So, each time, i'll need to send a new token to the server otherwise the user must re-login.

I'm having trouble with tab layout, where the request are simultaneous. Is there any way of sending request to the server only when a tab is active?

PS. I tried using handler which send the request after 2 seconds but it's not effective.

Comment: This is not related to `TabLayout`. It is in fact related to making synchronised API requests. Isn't it?

Comment: And I'm not convinced that you can do that by checking if your `TabLayout` is active/selected or not. For example, what if there are two buttons for requesting in the same tab?

Comment: I have two tabs, the first one is visible at the beginning so, the request is send on the "onCreate" methd . On the second tab though, i'll need to send the request only when its active.

Comment: You seem to be blocking the user from taking any action while data is being fetched from user. This is a bad UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this fragment method:

```
public class Your class extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);

        if (visible)
        {
            //launch task
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If opening the fragment on selecting tab, use below method in your fragment where you want to call your task. Below method is invoked only when the tab i selected and its respective fragment is fully visible.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
   ..................
   ..................

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

            if (isVisibleToUser) {

                //your code here

            }
    }

}
```